# How to Integrate Open API 3 with Spring project (not Spring Boot) using springdoc-openapi

Tags: java, spring, swagger-ui, openapi, springdoc

My Existing Project is on Spring Framework not Spring Boot.

I want to integrate Open API 3 with it.

I want to integrate using springdoc-openapi not using Jersey.

Answer (score 13):

The ui load for spring-mvc (5.3.1) using springdoc-openapi-ui 1.5.2 looks more simple:

build.gradle (gradle version 6.5)

```
implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.5.2'
```

The spring-boot-autoconfigure and spring-boot are not needed explicitly in dependencies section cause org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.5.2 already has them both (version 2.4.0).
You'll be surprised how many and what dependencies will be added to your final application.

OpenApiConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"org.springdoc"})
@Import({org.springdoc.core.SpringDocConfiguration.class,
         org.springdoc.webmvc.core.SpringDocWebMvcConfiguration.class,
         org.springdoc.webmvc.ui.SwaggerConfig.class,
         org.springdoc.core.SwaggerUiConfigProperties.class,
         org.springdoc.core.SwaggerUiOAuthProperties.class,
         org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration.class})

class OpenApiConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
}
```

The OpenApiConfig package should be covered by component scan.

In case of Spring Security usage, you might add two url patterns and define the role in your code for the OpenAPI pages access.

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/swagger*/**" access="ROLE_DEVELOPER"/>
<security:intercept-url pattern="/v3/api-docs" access="ROLE_DEVELOPER"/>
```

The urls to check:

```
http://localhost:8080/your_context_path/swagger-ui.html
http://localhost:8080/your_context_path/v3/api-docs
```

Comment: It works fine, and I can configure some "swagger-ui" properties (like `springdoc.swagger-ui.disable-swagger-default-url=true`). Nevertheless, if I try to disable "swagger-ui" an exception arises (using `springdoc.swagger-ui.enabled=false` property). Or setting `springdoc.swagger-ui.url` property takes no effect. Have you customized your "swagger-ui" any way?

Comment: I didn't need the import annotations. The component scan annotation was enough.

Comment: Is there a way to get this to work in Spring 4?  My project uses `spring-webmvc` v4.1.6 & I'm getting the following error: `Class 'OpenApiConfig' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'addFormatters(FormatterRegistry)' in 'WebMvcConfigurer'`.

Comment: Swagger openapi ui opening petstore

Answer (score 2):

Even your application is using spring without (spring-boot), it should work.
You need to add beans and dependencies auto-configuration that are natively provided in spring-boot.

You mainly, need to add the `springdoc-openapi` module and scan for the springdoc auto-configuration classes that `spring-boot` automatically loads for you.
Depending on your module, you can find them on the file: `spring.factories` of each `springdoc-openapi` module.

For example, lets assume you want load the `swagger-ui` in `spring-mvc` application, and you are using `spring.version=5.1.12.RELEASE`, and you

You can add the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.28</version>
</dependency>
```

If you don't have the `spring-boot` and `spring-boot-autoconfigure` dependencies, you need to add them. And pay attention to the compatibility matrix, between you `spring.verion` and `spring-boot.version`. For example, in this case (`spring.version=5.1.12.RELEASE`):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.11.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.11.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

In this case, as we want to load the ui for spring-mvc, you will need to add the following in one of your configuration classes:

```
@Import({ org.springdoc.core.SpringDocConfiguration.class, 
          org.springdoc.core.SpringDocWebMvcConfiguration.class,
          org.springdoc.ui.SwaggerConfig.class, 
          org.springdoc.core.SwaggerUiConfigProperties.class,
          org.springdoc.core.SwaggerUiOAuthProperties.class,
          org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration.class
})
```

Comment: Working like a charm

Comment: also did not work for me. No errors, but the application is not loaded.

Comment: @NunoSilva you confirmed its working on this ticket: https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues/250

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with **`@Annotations`**:

```
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.OpenAPIDefinition;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.servers.Server;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.info.Info

@OpenAPIDefinition(info = @Info(title = "My REST API", version = "1.2.6",
            description = "My OpenAPIDefinition description"),
                servers = { @Server(url = "/my-api", description = "Default URL")})
public class OpenApiConfig { }
```

Dependency of **Springdoc OpenAPI UI** on [Maven Central Repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springdoc/springdoc-openapi-ui):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Maven Central Repository:

- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springdoc/springdoc-openapi-ui

Comment: @cptully You're right, I made the correction, thank you very much for letting me know.

Answer (score 1):

In my Case to load the swagger-ui.html page, I used spring version 5.3.3 and springdoc-openapi-ui version 1.5.2.

My class configuration is:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.example")
@Import({org.springdoc.core.SpringDocConfiguration.class,
         org.springdoc.webmvc.core.SpringDocWebMvcConfiguration.class,
         org.springdoc.webmvc.ui.SwaggerConfig.class,
         org.springdoc.core.SwaggerUiConfigProperties.class,
         org.springdoc.core.SwaggerUiOAuthProperties.class,
         org.springdoc.core.SpringDocConfigProperties.class,
         org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration.class})
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer{

}
```

and my pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample project built with Spring and an embedded Undertow web server: https://github.com/essentialprogramming/undertow-spring-web
 No Spring Boot, even if it behaves like one. Just run the Server.*main* class. There you go, Open API will be available under ***http://localhost:8080/apidoc***

You just need to decorate the Spring WebApplicationContext with the required beans:

```
private static  AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext createSpringWebAppContext(String configLocation) {
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    context.setConfigLocation(configLocation);
    context.register(
            org.springdoc.core.SwaggerUiConfigProperties.class, org.springdoc.core.SwaggerUiOAuthProperties.class,
            org.springdoc.core.SpringDocConfiguration.class, org.springdoc.core.SpringDocConfigProperties.class,
            org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration.class);
    return context;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

### Documenting a Spring REST API Using OpenAPI 3.0

To document your spring boot application with OpenAPI 3.0, use this excellent article by baeldung.

```
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-openapi-documentation
```

Further, you can change the URI path of the swagger too.

```
springdoc.swagger-ui.path=/swagger
```

The above /swagger specifies my context path to host swagger.

now, my URI path to access my swagger dashboard becomes :

```
http://localhost:8080/swagger
```