# Configure Open API 3 on a Spring project (not Spring Boot)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, swagger, openapi, springdoc-openapi-ui

After following @Zagrebin-Victor [advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59871209/how-to-integrate-open-api-3-with-spring-project-not-spring-boot-using-springdo/59880655#59880655), I have a Spring MVC project running OpenAPI 3 (springdoc-openapi-1.5.3)

Following this [FAQ](https://springdoc.org/faq.html) I defined this on a property file:

```
springdoc.swagger-ui.disable-swagger-default-url=true
```

So no "Petstore API" is loaded by default.

Now, I would like to configure some of the properties documented on [Swagger-ui configuration](https://swagger.io/docs/open-source-tools/swagger-ui/usage/configuration/) web ("urls" property, for example). And that is the problem, I can not figure out how to configure the project

Not working if property put on:

1. "`src/main/resources/application.properies`" (though my application is not a Spring Boot one)
2. "`src/main/resources/swagger-config.yaml`"
3. Neither putting it as environment variable by code (ugly solution)

I found, and tried, another property notation as documented on this [GitHub thread](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/pull/12782). But no luck

Any idea?

Thank you very much

P.S: I do not want to configure swagger-ui putting parameters on the URL

Comment: have you got any luck after posted the question?

Comment: No. I am sorry, Nilson

Answer (score 0):

What finally worked for me with this problem was to skip any "properties" or "yaml" entirely. Instead I defined properties beans explicitly in the configuration class where the `OpenAPI` bean is provided:

```
public class OpenApiConfig {
      // ...
      // ...
      // ...

      @Bean
      public OpenAPI accOpenApi() {
          return new OpenAPI()
                  .info(apiInfo);
      }

      @Bean
      public SpringDocConfigProperties springDocConfigProperties() {
          SpringDocConfigProperties props = new SpringDocConfigProperties();
          props.setPackagesToScan(List.of("x.y.z"));
          props.setPathsToMatch(List.of("/api/**"));
          return props;
      }

      @Bean
      public SwaggerUiConfigProperties SwaggerUiConfigProperties() {
          SwaggerUiConfigProperties props = new SwaggerUiConfigProperties();
          props.setDisableSwaggerDefaultUrl(true);
          props.setDisplayRequestDuration(true);
          props.setTryItOutEnabled(true);
          props.setPath("/my-path-to/index.html");
          return props;
      }
}
```

I do not have `@Configuration` on top of this class, because I reference (and create) it from the xml configuration for the servlet context.

Comment: What are the dependencies you have used in your project?. I'm also working on Spring MVC application (non-boot), trying to figure out what are the required dependencies/configurations needed.

Comment: Currently for OpenAPI I have deps: `springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui` (with transient excludes of `spring-boot-autoconfigure` and `snakeyaml`), `springdoc-openapi-starter-common`, `springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-api` and explicit dep for `snakeyaml` with version 2.x (security concern).