# How do I configure a custom URL for the springdoc swagger-ui HTML page?

Tags: spring, springdoc, springdoc-openapi-ui

After adding the springdoc-openapi-ui dependency to my Spring project (not Spring Boot) OpenAPI V3 documentation is generated and can be viewed using the default swagger-ui page: `localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html`. Because the springdoc documentation replaces previous Swagger documentation I want to make it available at the same URL, `localhost:8080/docs/index.html`. Based on the springdoc documentation I get the impression that can be done by using the `springdoc.swagger-ui.path` option in the `application.properties`:

```
springdoc.swagger-ui.path=/docs/index.html
```

However, where I would expect to be able to navigate to the API documentation by going to `localhost:8080/docs/index.html` I get a 404 instead, `localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html` still works but now redirects to `http://localhost:8080/docs/swagger-ui/index.html?configUrl=/restapi/v3/api-docs/swagger-config`.

How can I configure my project too make the swagger-ui page available through a custom URL, i.e. `localhost:8080/docs/index.html` instead of the default `localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html`?

**Edit**

After trying some more to get it working and looking through the available information online, such as the springdoc [FAQ](https://springdoc.org/faq.html#how-to-integrate-open-api-3-with-spring-project-not-spring-boot) (mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68470670/14823855) answer by H3AR7B3A7) I couldn't get it working. I've decided to go with a different solution which should have the same effect. The `springdoc.swagger-ui.path` option allows specifying a custom URL but, as I understand it, going to the custom URL redirects a user to the standard `localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html` page. So the redirect is now configured manually:

```
@RequestMapping("/docs/index.html")
public void apiDocumentation(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
  response.sendRedirect("/swagger-ui.html");
}
```

Comment: This should work, although using 'localhost:8080/docs/index.html' will redirect you to 'http://localhost:8080/docs/swagger-ui/index.html?configUrl=/restapi/v3/api-docs/swagger-config'. Do you have any other related properties set? Or a config class that you can share? Using 'localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html' with these properties gives me a whitelabel.

Comment: Yeah, it was my understanding that if the `springdoc.swagger-ui.path` option worked you would be redirected to `http://localhost:8080/docs/swagger-ui/index.html?configUrl=/restapi/v3/api-docs/swagger-config`.
There is a config class that extends `AuthenticationStatelessContextConfiguration`, it overrides the `protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception` method and creates a `CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource()` bean. That seems to be the only config remotely possible to cause the problem but even that seems farfetched.

Comment: Hmm, that is weird behavior. Those config shouldn't be the problem, because localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html works. I was thinking of SpringDocConfiguration or SpringDocConfigProperties beans, because it looks like some other config is overwriting your properties, or your properties aren't being picked up for some reason.

Comment: If the code is not proprietary or sensitive in any way, I'd love to take a look... But otherwise there's not much more I can do than share my thoughts. XD

Comment: Maybe there is a config problem because it is a Spring application instead of a Spring Boot application and we don't properly config springdoc? Based on the springdoc FAQ the `org.springdoc.core.SpringDocConfiguration.class` and `org.springdoc.core.SpringDocConfigProperties.class` are added to the context. The default `localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html` works and the `springdoc.swagger-ui.path` option does something as the values configured show up in the URL to which you get redirected, although in a different form than I would expect.

Comment: We do have a URL base/prefix configured, could that be causing a conflict somehow? The name of the application gets added to the URL so instead of going to `localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html` you actually need to go to `localhost:8080/appname/swagger-ui.html`.

Comment: No, in my example I have set 'server.servlet.context-path: /appName'. Swagger should then just be available at 'localhost:8080/appname/index.html' and no longer at 'localhost:8080/appname/swagger-ui.html''. I still feel like your swagger-ui.path is not being picked up for some reason... All I can tell you for sure, is that it works for my project. XD

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar task for `Spring Boot 2.5.6` and `springdoc-openapi-webflux-ui 1.5.12`. I've found several possible solutions for myself. Maybe it will be helpful for somebody else.

---

#### Set `springdoc.swagger-ui.path` directly

The straightforward way is to set property `springdoc.swagger-ui.path=/custom/path`. It will work perfectly if you can hardcode `swagger` path in your application.

---

#### Override `springdoc.swagger-ui.path` property

You can change default `swagger-ui` path programmatically using `ApplicationListener<ApplicationPreparedEvent>`. The idea is simple -  override `springdoc.swagger-ui.path=/custom/path` before your Spring Boot application starts.

```java
@Component
public class SwaggerConfiguration implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationPreparedEvent> {

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(final ApplicationPreparedEvent event) {
        ConfigurableEnvironment environment = event.getApplicationContext().getEnvironment();
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("springdoc.swagger-ui.path", swaggerPath());
        environment.getPropertySources()
                .addFirst(new PropertiesPropertySource("programmatically", props));
    }

    private String swaggerPath() {
        return "/swagger/path"; //todo: implement your logic here.
    }
}
```

In this case, you must register the listener before your application start:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@OpenAPIDefinition(info = @Info(title = "APIs", version = "0.0.1", description = "APIs v0.0.1"))
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication application = new SpringApplication(App.class);
        application.addListeners(new SwaggerConfiguration());
        application.run(args);
    }
}
```

---

#### Redirect using controller

You can also register your own controller and make a simple redirect (the same as what you suggest, but in my case, I need to use the `WebFlux` approach):

```
@RestController
public class SwaggerEndpoint {

    @GetMapping("/custom/path")
    public Mono<Void> api(ServerHttpResponse response) {
        response.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.PERMANENT_REDIRECT);
        response.getHeaders().setLocation(URI.create("/swagger-ui.html"));
        return response.setComplete();
    }
}
```

The problem with such an approach - your server will still respond if you call it by address `"/swagger-ui.html"`.

Answer (score 2):

Apparantly the library integrates natively only with spring-boot applications like you mentioned in your comment.
If you want to use spring, it's possible but the integration details aren't documented, because it really depends on the version/module and the nature of you spring application.

You can check the [FAQ](https://springdoc.org/faq.html#how-to-integrate-open-api-3-with-spring-project-not-spring-boot) to see if it answers your questions.

There are some more answers [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59871209/how-to-integrate-open-api-3-with-spring-project-not-spring-boot-using-springdo/59880655#59880655).

Answer (score 0):

I solved by a clear code.
The problem is in webflux that security need permitAll for some uri resources so I solved in this mode in WebFlux Security I image the same in Springboot no WebFlux:

```
                .authorizeExchange().pathMatchers(
// START To show swagger 3:
                        "/swagger-ui.html",
                        "/webjars/swagger-ui/**",
                        "/v3/api-docs/swagger-config",
                        "/v3/api-docs", // This is the one URI resource used by openApi3 too.
// END To show swagger 3:
                        "/other-uri-permitAll",
                        ...
                        "/other-uri-permitAll_N",
                   .permitAll()
                .and()
                .authorizeExchange().pathMatchers(
                        "/other-uri-authenticated-only_1",
                        "...",
                        "/other-uri-authenticated-only_1")
                    .authenticated()
                .and()
                .authenticationManager(myAuthenticationManager)
                .securityContextRepository(mySecurityContextRepository)
                .authorizeExchange().anyExchange().authenticated()
                .and()
                .build();
```