# spring-doc open api integration on spring web mvc problem

Tags: java, spring, swagger, springdoc, springdoc-openapi-ui

I am working on a production application built with spring core, spring Web-mvc, spring security. It is running fine. But I want to implement spring doc Open-Api. So I am using first solution of this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59871209/how-to-integrate-open-api-3-with-spring-project-not-spring-boot-using-springdo).

i have made following changes to integrate spring doc open api:

```
file-build.gradle:


implementation (group: 'org.springdoc', name: 'springdoc-openapi-ui', version: '1.6.13'){
    exclude group: 'org.springframework', module: 'spring-webmvc'
}
```

code here

```
file: servlet-context.xml:

<!-- Package scan for spring doc open ui -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.documentation.openapiconfig"/>
```

Created new package com.documentation.openapiconfig and have only one class in this:

```
package com.documentation.openapiconfig;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"org.springdoc"})
@Import({org.springdoc.core.SpringDocConfiguration.class,
         org.springdoc.webmvc.core.SpringDocWebMvcConfiguration.class,
         org.springdoc.webmvc.ui.SwaggerConfig.class,
         org.springdoc.core.SwaggerUiConfigProperties.class,
         org.springdoc.core.SwaggerUiOAuthProperties.class,
         org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration.class})

class OpenApiConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
}
```

In spring-security.xml, I have changed the following:

```
 <security:intercept-url pattern="/swagger*/**" access="ROLE_DEVELOPER"/>
<security:intercept-url pattern="/v3/api-docs" access="ROLE_DEVELOPER"/>
```

AFter these changes, when i run the application i get following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'exceptionHandlingController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'eliteUtils'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'eliteUtils': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'staffService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'staffService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'systemParamService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'systemParameterService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'staffService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'auditAspect': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'eliteUtils'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'eliteUtils': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:702)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:716)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:591)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:530)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:170)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1089)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:983)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4876)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5185)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:468)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat$start$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:115)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:119)
    at org.akhikhl.gretty.TomcatServerManager.startServer(TomcatServerManager.groovy:52)
    at org.akhikhl.gretty.ServerManager$startServer$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:115)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:127)
    at org.akhikhl.gretty.Runner.run(Runner.groovy:129)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PlainObjectMetaMethodSite.doInvoke(PlainObjectMetaMethodSite.java:43)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:190)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:70)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:115)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:119)
    at org.akhikhl.gretty.Runner.main(Runner.groovy:54)



Any one please help, it's urgent.
```

Comment: How about removing exclude group: 'org.springframework'?

Comment: In my project, spring-web mvc is already present. If i am keeping spring-web mvc , It is causing problem. It is showing AbstractExcelView is not present.

Comment: As of Spring 4.2, instead of AbstractExcelView you can try AbstractXlsView and its AbstractXlsxView and AbstractXlsxStreamingView variants